# Send MMS under Ubuntu with 3G USB modem

Tags: ubuntu, 3g, modem, mms

I am looking for a way to send MMS under Ubuntu 13.10 to my mobile phone using 3g Huwaei e371 modem.

I found some application called "mbuni", but it is very complicated and hard to configure. 
http://www.mbuni.org/index.shtml

Does anybody know how can I do it?

I don't want to create MMSC or sth like that, only send MMS.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off coding a simple command-line app with [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/).

EDIT: After having a look, you would very much be better off coding a simple app with Twilio, every solution looks to be fairly complicated, that said I found [this](http://tuxmobil.org/phones_linux_sms.html) site which might be useful to you.